# Bringing my Japanese akita dog with me from Europe to the US, preferably in cabin

Tags: air-travel, pets

I would like to bring my Japanese akita dog with me from Europe to the US. And I would really like it to be with me in the cabin. Which air companies allow that?

Comment: Note that our answers over there are very much out of date.

Comment: @ZachLipton They're also about *small* dogs in the cabin, which an Akita is definitely not.

Comment: A quick Google found a more recent compendium of in-cabin pet rules [here.](http://www.sheknows.com/pets-and-animals/articles/974085/airlines-that-allow-pets-in-cabin)  In all cases, in-cabin pets must be under 25 lbs and/or be able to fit in a carrier under the seat.  An akita is (pardon the pun) not going to fly this way.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You should make that an answer.